# Ampersand (&) operator in MySql WHERE Clause

Tags: mysql, sql

What this passage does? **(xyz & 192 > 0)** in

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (xyz & 192 > 0)
```

**192** is created from two values **64 + 128**

**xyz** can be: **1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128** ... or the sum of some of these values, for example **64+128**

Comment: So your question is?????????

Comment: What does this fragment do `(xyz & 192> 0)`

Comment: Does this help? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/bit-functions.html#operator_bitwise-and

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the bitwise AND operator:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/bit-functions.html#operator_bitwise-and

which performs AND on each pair of bits in the two arguments:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND

and has higher precedence than >

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/operator-precedence.html

```
INTERVAL
BINARY, COLLATE
!
- (unary minus), ~ (unary bit inversion)
^
*, /, DIV, %, MOD
-, +
<<, >>
&
|
= (comparison), <=>, >=, >, <=, <, <>, !=, IS, LIKE, REGEXP, IN, MEMBER OF
BETWEEN, CASE, WHEN, THEN, ELSE
NOT
AND, &&
XOR
OR, ||
= (assignment), :=
```

Answer (score 2):

(xyz & 192 > 0) checks if the sum xyz has the elements either 64 and/or 128 as its values

Comment: what about 72, 96, 144 or 192?  Or 384?  I think there are more values than that where this is true.

Comment: 72 = 64 + 8; it will be true because it has 64 as element. 96 = 64 + 32 also true as it contains 64. 144 = 128 + 16 is true because it contains 128. 192 = 128+64 is true because it contains 64 (and or) 128. 384 = 256 + 128 is true because it contains 128.

Answer (score 2):

This is not intended to be an answer.
The answers of Chris & Tom combined explain it.
But I was wondering how the bitwise-AND operator resulted for different numbers.

> ```
> with recursive NUMS (num) as (
>   select 1 as num
>   union all
>   select num+1
>   from NUMS
>   where num < 575
> )
> select min(num) minNum, max(num) maxNum
> , (num & 192) as chk
> from NUMS
> group by chk, cast((num - MOD(num, 64))/64 as unsigned)
> ```
>
> ```
> minNum | maxNum | chk
> -----: | -----: | --:
>      1 |     63 |   0
>     64 |    127 |  64
>    128 |    191 | 128
>    192 |    255 | 192
>    256 |    319 |   0
>    320 |    383 |  64
>    384 |    447 | 128
>    448 |    511 | 192
>    512 |    575 |   0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c574bd46c6ac54ac940e046a9687bd00)*

So okay, `(xyz & 192 > 0)` could be used to verify if xyz is between 64 and 255.

Comment: Nice.  Consider this fiddle where n & 192 > 0 https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=a61057fa9b124b9d52874ee903dd21a2

Comment: @ChrisStrickland Haha, nice one.  Still, i.m.h.o. I would never use such a check myself. *(unless it's for golfcoding)* It's just not intuitive.

Comment: I'm with you on that.  I know that bitwise operation can save some flops, but why?  Modern coding is generally based around readability and not slight optimization.  I would be very curious about the context of this question.

Comment: Also, bitwise and between seem to produce the same cost: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=fd17a69c8663a26da42cedacdbc35ca5

Comment: @ChrisStrickland I found it in application code, i don't know why someone used it. The author of the code no longer works with us.